# How to add sub row in table on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a dynamic table where I can add rows and Sub rows on button click.

Currently I have 2 features:

- on Group button click, add a new row,
- on Genre button click, add a new sub row inside the same genre,

On Group button click I can Add a new row and it works fine, but in any group, If I try to add 2+ genres, then the table layout gets messed up.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#my_table button.2ndName', function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr");

  var nrid = $row.find(".nr").attr('rowspan');

  if (nrid == null) {
    nrid = 1;
  }

  nrid++;
  $row.find(".nr").attr('rowspan', nrid);
  var newRow = $("<tr>");
  var cols = "";
  var $td = $(this).closest("td");
  $td.find("#btn").hide();

  cols += '<td><input type="text" placeholder="" size="13" /><button class="2ndName" id="btn">+</button></td>    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" size="7"></td><td><input type="text"placeholder="" size="7"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="" size="7"></td"><td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td><td><input type="text" size="10" placeholder=""></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="" size="7"></td><td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td><td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td></tr>';
  newRow.append(cols);

  newRow.insertAfter($(this).parents().closest('tr'));

});

$(document).on('click', '#my_table button.site', function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr");

  var newRow = $("<tr>");
  var cols = "";
  var $td = $(this).closest("td");
  $td.find("#btn").hide();

  cols += '<td class="nr"><input type="text" placeholder="" size="9"><button id="btn" class="site" style="float:right;">+</button></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="" size="13"><button class="2ndName" id="btn" style="float:right;">+</button></td><td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td><td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td><td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td><td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td><td><input type="text" size="10" placeholder=""></td><td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td><td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td><td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td></tr>';
  newRow.append(cols);

  newRow.insertAfter($(this).parents().closest('tr'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="my_table" id="my_table" border="1px" style="border-collapse: collapse;">

  <tr>
    <td>Group</td>
    <td>Genre</td>
    <td>Movie Name</td>
    <td>Imdb</td>
    <td>Rotten Tomato</td>
    <td>Lead Actress</td>
    <td>Lead Actor</td>
    <td>Year of Release</td>
    <td>Revenue</td>
    <td>Budget</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="nr"><input type="text" placeholder="" size="9"><button id="btn" class="site" style="float:right;">+</button>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" size="13"><button class="2ndName" id="btn" style="float:right;">+</button></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="10" placeholder=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="7" placeholder=""></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well... I done it with JS

```js
const myTable = document.querySelector('#my-table tbody')   // Where it all happens
  ,   RowBase = myTable.querySelector('tr').cloneNode(true) // Copy ref for each new line
  ;
myTable.querySelector('tr button.onGenre').TD_Group = myTable.querySelector('tr td')  // tell him who it belongs to
  ;
myTable.onclick=e=>   // for any click on the table
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button.onGroup, button.onGenre')) return // except the others

  let OnButton = e.target                 // and Adam named each thing...
    , newRow   = RowBase.cloneNode(true)  // future new row
    ;
  if (OnButton.className==='onGroup')     // it's him !
    {
    newRow.querySelector('tr button.onGenre').TD_Group = newRow.querySelector('tr td') // this one belong to the new
    myTable.appendChild( newRow )
    }
  else // (OnButton.className==='onGenre')      // it's the other !
    {
    newRow.querySelector('td').remove()                                    // remove <td...  button class="onGroup" ...td>
    newRow.querySelector('tr button.onGenre').TD_Group = OnButton.TD_Group // this one belong where is his reference onGroup

    let nRowSp = parseInt(OnButton.TD_Group.getAttribute('rowspan')) +1    // compute new val for rowspan
    OnButton.TD_Group.setAttribute('rowspan', nRowSp )                     // put it on

    OnButton.parentNode.parentNode.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',newRow )  // to add  the new row in the right place
    }
  OnButton.remove();  // that's the law: any clicked button must disappear!
  }


/* ----------------------------------------------------- *\
|  special delivery -> how to recover the entered values  |
\* ----------------------------------------------------- */ 

const ColsNames = [...document.querySelectorAll('#my-table thead td')].map(e=>e.textContent)  // get all columns names
  ,   ColsN_Nb  = ColsNames.length            // will not change, so much to know right away
  ;
document.getElementById('Bt-get-table-inputs').onclick=_=>  // I did not find a simpler name
  {
  let Resp    = []    // future solution
    , Grp_id  = 0     // we always need a reference
    , Grp_Elm = null  // out of respect for gregarious nature
    ;
  myTable.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(xTR=>   // get each row
    {
      let inVals = xTR.querySelectorAll('input') // get all inputs
        , newGrp = (inVals.length === ColsN_Nb)  // if inputs numbers is full, or not
        ;
      if (newGrp) 
        {
        Grp_id++  // set new ref
        Resp.push( { id:Grp_id, Group:inVals[0].value, elm:[] } ) 
        Grp_Elm = Resp[(Grp_id-1)].elm  // everything will belong to him
        }
      let vals = {}
      inVals.forEach((inV,i)=>
        {
        if (!newGrp)   vals[ ColsNames[i+1]] = inV.value
        else if (i>0)  vals[ ColsNames[i]]   = inV.value
        })
      Grp_Elm.push( vals )
    })

  console.log(JSON.stringify(Resp,0,2 )  )  // for testing
  }
```

```css
#my-table {
  margin-top: 3em;
  border-collapse : collapse;
  font-family     : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size       : 14px;
}
#my-table thead td {
  background-color : turquoise;
  text-align       : center;
  padding          : .7em 0;
  white-space      : nowrap;
}
#my-table tbody td {
  width          : 1em;
  vertical-align : top;
} 
#my-table td           { border           : 1px solid gray; } 
#my-table tbody        { background-color : lightsteelblue; }
#my-table tbody button { float            : right;            }

/* just to test snippet  */
#Bt-get-table-inputs { position: fixed; top:0.5em; left:1em }
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; width: 40% !important; top: 0; left: 60% !important; }
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Group</td><td>Genre</td><td>Movie Name</td><td>Imdb</td><td>Rotten Tomato</td>
      <td>Lead Actress</td><td>Lead Actor</td><td>Year of Release</td><td>Revenue</td><td>Budget</td>
    </tr>      
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1"><input type="text" size="9"  placeholder=""><button class="onGroup"> + </button></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="13" placeholder=""><button class="onGenre" > + </button></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="7"  placeholder=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="7"  placeholder=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="7"  placeholder=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="7"  placeholder=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="10" placeholder=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="7"  placeholder=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="7"  placeholder=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="7"  placeholder=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Just for test getting values -->
<button id="Bt-get-table-inputs">Get All values</button>
```

*I don't think it can be done that simply with jQuery* ;)
*Full screen is better to show snippet*

Comment: Hi Mister Jojo, this looks good, however theres a tiny problem, every Group should have a button to add Genre in the last Genre, currently if I add a new Group, the add genre button of the previous group disappears..

Comment: looks good, thank you. By the way, is it complicated to retrive data from the dynamically created table on a form submit? thats my next step.., if possible can you give me code for it too?

Comment: @asmijkun Yes I can do that too, but I would prefer that you first say what's wrong with my code so that I can fix it. or do you think that my code does not deserve the slightest point or validation?

Comment: sorry If you think I did not validate your answer, your answer is very accurate. But tbh, its hard for me to understand your code as I've not worked with such complicated JS. I agree with you though, the code looks cleaner than Jquery code. Can I ask you to put some more comments to help me understand the code better? I've started learning JS now so I can understand your code better.

Comment: Update, I dont need the data retreival code anymore, I was confused on how to convert the dynamically created table to html so I can submit it, but Jquery has a method .clone() which I can use to clone the dynamically created table, and the result is a html table.

Comment: @I added the comments. and also the way to recover the input in JSON

Comment: Hi Mister Jojo, thanks a lot for your response, I will validate your code tomorrow

Comment: Dear Mister Jojo, thanks a lot for adding the comments and for the special delivery ;) I loved the fact that the JSON output nests the different genres under the same group. It makes parsing the data very simple. In my approach I just cloned the dynamic table and it gave me a html table which required further parsing inorder to convert it into the sql queries Your approach with the JSON output makes it easier for me Thanks, I will be learning Javascript in more detail now, I always thought JQuery was a better version of JS but as it turned out some problems can be solved by JS more efficiently

Comment: @asmijkun jQuery was very useful at a time when browsers betrayed standards (MS-IE) to kill their competitors. Cleared of this war, JS can now flourish and advance further than jQuery could. In any case happy to have put you on this path :))

Answer (score 0):

your problem is quite simple to solve. This is my mini version of what you have [here](https://codepen.io/mankinchi/pen/JjoVBEJ?editors=1010).

Basically the problem is this:

- You have your code to update the `rowspan` of the group cell. However, this only works if you are still on the same row (or first insert). On the second insert, since you don't have the group cell anymore, your code fails.

Some extra tips:

- If you are planning to go with jQuery, maybe learn about element creation using jQuery (I did that in my link), I think it will make your code looks clearer
- Have proper string for id and class. That will help you distinguish things easier.

Comment: Dear @Tree, thank you for your answer and suggestions to improve the code, however your code is buggy as well. Try the following: In the first group, create 3 genres, then create a new group and create 3 genres as well, the table layout will break.

Comment: @asmijkun sr I made an unsaved change. Please check again.

Comment: looks good, thank you. By the way, is it complicated to retrive data from the dynamically created table on a form submit? thats my next step, If possible can you give me code for it too?

Answer (score 0):

The rowspan is not updating each time you click on the 'button.2ndName" it's only happening first time where it sets to rowspan=2 that's why it's working for the first two rows.